# Why MaxValue and Nmaximize doesnt aproximately match?

Tags: performance-tuning

I want to find the maximum value of the following function of three variables $(x>0,y>0,z>0)$:

```
f=Sqrt[16+1/(2 x^2 y^2 z^4)]-1/2 Sqrt[(1+x^2 y^2 z^4 (96+Sqrt[8256+(1+144 x^2 y^2 z^4)/(x^4 y^4 z^8)])+8 x^4 y^4 z^8 (408+5 Sqrt[8256+(1+144 x^2 y^2 z^4)/(x^4 y^4 z^8)]))/(x^2 y^2 z^4+104 x^4 y^4 z^8)];
```

Particularly, I am using the `Maxvalue[]` and `NMazimize[]` functions 
in order to inspect such maximum value:

```
N[MaxValue[Sqrt[16+1/(2 x^2 y^2 z^4)]-1/2 Sqrt[(1+x^2 y^2 z^4 (96+Sqrt[8256+(1+144 x^2 y^2 z^4)/(x^4 y^4 z^8)])+8 x^4 y^4 z^8 (408+5 Sqrt[8256+(1+144 x^2 y^2 z^4)/(x^4 y^4 z^8)]))/(x^2 y^2 z^4+104 x^4 y^4 z^8)],{y,x,z}]]

NMaximize[Sqrt[16+1/(2 x^2 y^2 z^4)]-1/2 Sqrt[(1+x^2 y^2 z^4 (96+Sqrt[8256+(1+144 x^2 y^2 z^4)/(x^4 y^4 z^8)])+8 x^4 y^4 z^8 (408+5 Sqrt[8256+(1+144 x^2 y^2 z^4)/(x^4 y^4 z^8)]))/(x^2 y^2 z^4+104 x^4 y^4 z^8)],{x>0&&y>0&&z>0},{y,x,z}]
```

I think that these numerical values ​​should *approximately* coincide, however, they do not match! 
`Maxvalue[]` function yields the result of $\approx 0.384$ and `Nmaximize[]` yields $\approx 0.468$, so, the questions are:

1. Why `Nmaximize[]` and `Nmaximize[]`  does not yield an approximately similar maximum value?
2. Which is the true maximum value of the function?

Answer (score 4):

Since x,y,z always appear together in the term `x^2 y^2 z^4` ,
introduce a new variable r.

```
sol = Solve[x^2 y^2 z^4 == r, x]

f2 = FullSimplify[f /. sol[[2]], r > 0]

{maxval = MaxValue[{f2, r > 0}, r] // FullSimplify, maxval // N}

(*   {\[Sqrt]Root[
  155155693568 - 711878246400 #1 + 20137902080 #1^2 + 
 6553272320 #1^3 - 359198720 #1^4 + 6108160 #1^5 + 303488 #1^6 + 
 3920 #1^7 + 9 #1^8 &, 3], 0.468413}   *)

Plot[f2, {r, -1, 1/2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

**Edit**

The maximum is reached everywhere on the hyperspace where `x^2*y^2*z^4 == rmax` .

```
{maxi = Maximize[{f2, r > 0}, r] // FullSimplify, maxi // N}

ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[x^2 y^2 z^4 == (r /. maxi[[2]])], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

actually,you may use `Maximize` to get the global max value.

```
Maximize[{Sqrt[16 + 1/(2 x^2 y^2 z^4)] - 
   1/2 Sqrt[(1 + 
        x^2 y^2 z^4 (96 + 
           Sqrt[8256 + (1 + 144 x^2 y^2 z^4)/(x^4 y^4 z^8)]) + 
        8 x^4 y^4 z^8 (408 + 
           5 Sqrt[8256 + (1 + 
                 144 x^2 y^2 z^4)/(x^4 y^4 z^8)]))/(x^2 y^2 z^4 + 
        104 x^4 y^4 z^8)], x > 0, y > 0, z > 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

which returns

```
{-Root[155155693568 - 711878246400 #1^2 + 20137902080 #1^4 + 
     6553272320 #1^6 - 359198720 #1^8 + 6108160 #1^10 + 
     303488 #1^12 + 3920 #1^14 + 9 #1^16 &, 2], {x -> 1, 
  y -> Root[-1 - 312 #1^2 - 16320 #1^4 + 6009344 #1^6 + 
      1273081856 #1^8 + 113866014720 #1^10 + 5415138754560 #1^12 + 
      129815543808000 #1^14 + 1084423038566400 #1^16 &, 2], z -> 1}}
```

then you can use `//N` to get the number.

$\{0.468413,\{x\to 1.,y\to 0.0753346,z\to 1.\}\}$

`// ToRadicals` can help get the "sqrt" form. but since the result can't be shown.you know the reason.

Comment: @BobHanlon thx,I have corrected my answer.